# How to make and write a JSON file in WebStorm

Tags: json, webstorm

I am trying to write a `JSON` file, but every time I create a new file it comes up as a text file, after that I try to add the `.json` extension, but it stays as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have `<some name>.json` patterns added to text file patterns in **Settings | Editor | File types -> Text** file type. Removing these pattern(s) should solve the syntax highlighting issue.

To create a new `.json` file, use **New > File**, specifying both name and extension as a new file name:

[image]